# XML data in datagridview (Winform) doesn't show the rows but just first row of processing instruction

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, datagridview

I am using a datagrid and using the following code to show the xml file values ( 3 rows and 2 columns). However, I am just getting xml version row. Please help me what change it requires to display all rows?

```
        DataSet D = new DataSet();
        D.ReadXml(@"C:\myFamilie.xml");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = D.Tables[0];
```

### XML

- -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `DataSource` to the `Dataset D`, and then set `DataMember` to the `Families` (or whatever the name of the Element containing your 3 rows inside the Xml file is named).

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = D;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Families";
```

Assuming your Xml looks something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<FamiliesTable>
  <Families>
    <name>Family 1</name>
    <members>5</members>
  </Families>
  <Families>
    <name>Family 2</name>
    <members>3</members>
  </Families>
  <Families>
    <name>Family 3</name>
    <members>8</members>
  </Families>
</FamiliesTable>
```

Comment: Still not getting Shiva. 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<xml encoding="utf-8" version="1.0"> -<Familie> <Father Age="65" Name="My father"/> <Mother Age="60" Name="My mother"/> <Sister Age="20" Name="My sister"/> <Brother Age="21" Name="My brother"/> </Familie> </xml>

Comment: Can you paste the Xml into your question and format it? So I can see exactly how your xml looks like.

Comment: Ok your example works. Perhaps I should have same element name repeatedly? My XML above doesnt work. Anyway. I am learning XML today. Thank you thala ;) It would be great if you can explain me the reason....

Comment: Mapillai, I think it's because you have field values as xml element attributes. Ex: Mother has Age="60" and Name="My Mother". Do you have control over how this Xml is formatted? Also check out this walkthrough that might help you understand this better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ekw4dh3f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks thala, sorry thoongitten, couldn't reply immediately. I am learning xml :) I will read the link you gave now itself...Thala I see that you live in US :0 I wanna come to US too :( Help me? :(